# Как запустить функцию при нажатии на список Listbox() (Tkinter , Python)

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

В tkinter есть отдельный виджет , который обрабатывает события . Но мне нужно , чтобы событие обрабатывалось при нажатии на элемент списка Listbox() Вопрос : можно ли это сделать , и если можно , то как ?

Answer (score 0):

С помощью метода

```
bind(self, sequence=None, func=None, add=None)
       Bind to this widget at event SEQUENCE a call to function FUNC
```

1. Привязываете к listbox функцию обработчик щелчка
2. В этой функции считываете игдекс выбранного элемента списка
3. По индексу определяете, что нужно делать дальше...